# Using JRun 4 with IIS Express 7.5, is it possible?

Tags: iis-express, jrun

Is there anyway configure IIS Express 7.5 to utilize JRun 4 for jsp pages?

We are currently trying to get through rewriting our remaining Java Server Pages to ASP.NET but until this is completed, is the fact that we still have some, gonna force us to continue using the full version of IIS during development?

I'm new to IIS Express and for that fact, I'm also new to the configuration method of IIS 7.x all together, we're still on 6. Thanks in advance for any help or guidance.